# Is it safe to use process_post within a callback function of Rime? - Contiki

Tags: contiki

I am working with Rime, more specifically with the runicast example. Once a message is received i store it in a linked list, then i post an event to a process which is in charge of extracting messages from the linked list and processing them. My code is something like this:

```
 static void recv_runicast(struct runicast_conn *c, 
                           const linkaddr_t *from, uint8_t seqno)
 {

     /*code to insert the message into the linked list*/
     ...

    /*Post an event to the process which extracts messages from the linked list */
    process_post(&extract_msg_from_linked_list, PROCESS_EVENT_CONTINUE, NULL);
 }
```

My question is: Is it safe to use process_post within the callback function recv_runicast? or should i use process_poll?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. The network stack operations are done in process context, and Contiki processes are not preemptive. So pretty much any process-related operations are "safe".

The main differences between `process_post` and `process_poll` is that the former will put a new event in the process event buffer, while the latter will simply set a flag. So the second options is slightly more efficient. Also, in theory the event buffer can get full and events start to get lost, but that's *very* unlikely to be a problem.

I would use none of these functions at all, but do the processing directly in the callback to simplify the execution flow.